# How to remove borders around a contained image link?

Tags: html, css

There is a border around the container which is white in color. I tried the border: 0; rule but it doesn't remove it at all.

EDIT: http://mpkosis28.com

CSS:

```css
#content {
  height: 350px;
  width: 700px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#content img {
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  background: url(../images/awd/boxas.png) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 300px;
}
#content a img {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="content" align="center">
  <h1 class="centeredImage"><a href="http://goo.gl/forms/oXBZKgpFzk"><img></a></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: better to show your environment, the snippet worked unexpected.

Comment: the answer from @myfriend seemed helps

Comment: Put a real image in there (instead of an empty `<img>` tag) and your problem will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

This must work:

```
#content a img {
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: The border is still there, tried both `0` and `none` and the outline. They don't affect the border at all.

Answer (score 0):

First Set image tag attribute `border = 0` in your html file

and in css file change like this.

```
#content a{
    border:none;
    outline:none;
}

#content a img{
    border:none;
    outline:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the image source in the regular fashion like `<img src="..." />` instead of as a `background` css property it will not show the border. Is there a reason why you need to set it as a `background` property?

Answer (score 0):

It is just the browser implementation of showing that the `src` attribute `<img>` doesn't have valid image link.

Solution for your code:

1. copy the background url from the css to src attribute of the `<img>`.
2. change the `<img>` to `<div>`, and adjust it according to your requirements.